# Permutation of multiple groups of different sizes

Tags: combinatorics

While working on my research for my master thesis I have stumbled upon the following problem:

Given $N$ groups of different sizes, create all the possible combinations $p$ such that:
 $p = \{e_{0,j_0},e_{1,j_1},...,e_{N,j_k}\}$ for all $e_{i,j}$.

where $i$ stands for the index of the group and $j$ stands for the index of the element of group $n_j$.

For example: given $\{ 1,2,3\}$ and $\{ a,b,c,d\}$
the answer would be :

$\{ 1,a\}$, $\{ 2,a\}$,$\{ 3,a\}$

$\{ 1,b\}$, $\{ 2,b\}$,$\{ 3,b\}$

$\{ 1,c\}$, $\{ 2,c\}$,$\{ 3,c\}$

$\{ 1,d\}$, $\{ 2,d\}$,$\{ 3,d\}$

The way I solve it is by using an odometer counter, where each digit is of base $size(n_i)$, and I generate all the combinations by simply increasing the odometer until it resets to 0.

Given the previous example, the odometer would be composed of two digits, $(d_0,d_1)$ where $d_0$ would be of base $3$ and $d_1$ would be of base $4$ and the enumeration of all the group would look like :

$(0,0)$,$(1,0)$,$(2,0)$

$(0,1)$,$(1,1)$,$(2,1)$
.
.
.
etc

The problem I have is that the run time of my implementation is not fast enough given a large number of groups. It works fine for 16 groups but starts to really slow down for 32 groups.

Before I go into optimizing my implementation, I wanted to know if there was a theoretical solution that is more efficient than the one I am currently using.

Comment: If you have 64 groups, each containing more than one element, then you have at least $2^{64}$ combinations, which is a lot. I doubt that you are going over all of them.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I was thinking of block sizes. The number of groups is 1/4 of the block size. so 16 and 32. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: When you have 16 groups of 4, there are $2^{32}$ possibilities, a large but reasonable number. When you have 32 groups of 4, there are $2^{64}$ possibilities, which is more than a standard computer can handle in any reasonable amount of time. You cannot realistically expect to go over so many possibilities.